# Backbone, require.js and the Youtube Javascript API

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, youtube-api, requirejs

I'm using a require.js youtube api module to load multiple youtube videos onto my site and I'm having some trouble use the API to control said videos on the site once they are in place. Basically, I can't seem to find a way to reference the 'player' variable that gets created, and then use all the methods like .pauseVideo(), .playVideo(), etc.

What I want to do is do a check to make sure that ALL videos on the page are stopped when the user clicks a button. I'm having trouble thinking through how to accomplish that, however.

Here is my code:

Youtube require.js module

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player = {
        loadPlayer: function(container, videoId, width, height) {
            new YT.Player(container, {
                videoId: videoId,
                width: width,
                height: height,
                playerVars: {
                    autoplay: 0,
                    controls: 1,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    rel: 0,
                    showInfo: 0
                }
            });
        }
    };

    return player;
});
```

This module (I named it YouTubeAPI) is called four or five or however many times is needed, depending on the amount of videos on the page. I basically check for the dom for how many youtube containers there are, each has a data object on them containing the youtube id for the clip, run all of that through a for loop that uses the youtube require module. Not AT ALL certain this is best approach, so advice is appreciated.

```
youTubePlayer: function(){
    var self = this;

    if ($('.slidevideo').length){
        _.each($('.slidevideo'), function(el){
            var YTid = $(el).data('videoid');
            youTubeAPI.loadPlayer('Player-'+YTid, YTid, self.span8width, self.window_height-150);
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: I think you should import the YouTube API using a RequireJS shim.

Answer (score 2):

If you define a module and place Google's YT loader into it, then return `YT` to any 'inheriting' module, then it should work.

Here's the one I made just now.

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone){
  if (!window['YT']) {
      var YT = window['YT'] = { loading: 0, loaded: 0 };
  }
  if (!window['YTConfig']) {
      var YTConfig = window['YTConfig'] = {};
  }
  if (!YT.loading) {
      YT.loading = 1;
      (function(){
          var l = [];
          YT.ready = function(f) {
              if (YT.loaded) {
                  f();
              } 
              else {
                  l.push(f);
              }
          };
          window.onYTReady = function() {
              YT.loaded = 1;
              for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                  try { l[i](); } catch (e) { }
              }
          };
          YT.setConfig = function(c) {
              for (var k in c) {
                  if (c.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                      YTConfig[k] = c[k];
                  }
              }
          };
          var a = document.createElement('script');
          a.src = 'http:' + '//s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflAfnlMi.js';
          a.async = true;
          var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
      })();
  }
  return YT;
});
```

And then you reference this module in your View, or whichever module is handling you video player. If I save the above module to `helpers/youtube-loader`, I can refer via the require file loader like this:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'helpers/youtube-loader'
], function(_, Backbone, YT){
  var id = 'W8MLqYNGKdI'
  // uses global scope to use this reference in a YouTube API event listener
  var player = window['player'] = new YT.Player('yt-player', {
        height: '400',
        width: '730',
        videoId: id
    });
});
```

Worth noting that I had to use the `window` reference as a duplicate of the internal require.js object in order for it to load error free.

Also, the URL of the script in the loader may be liable to change... possible alternative is to use local copy.

Comment: When I try this I get a Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at new YT.Player ('',{}). So I removed the new keyword since its whats causing the problem then I get Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Player'. When I console.log YT I get Object {loading: 1, loaded: 0, ready: function, setConfig: function} which suggest that I am getting back a object on further inspection of I realize that the object contain a Player: function so why is this not working?

Comment: Very difficult to say without seeing your code... if you make a new question and paste your code, then send the link here, I'll try to help.